# How to install 3.0.1 VLC Player on elementary os?

Tags: vlc

When I use Ubuntu on videolan.org site and click donwload VLC it simply opens apt://vlc link and I can install vlc.

However elementary os does not support that kind of links. I tried to find a .deb file but can't find it.

So how to install vlc 3.0.1 on elementary os?

Comment: I usually use gDebi to install this kind of packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first option: *using snap (current version: [3.0.1-4-g14a4897](https://snapcraft.io/vlc)*

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

then

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

second option: *(stable version 2.2.2 last update: 32 weeks ago)*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

third option: *(beta version 4.0.0~rc1 last update 23hours ago) **not recommended***

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend installing VLC as a snap using Snaptastic.

1. Install [Snaptastic](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.bartzaalberg.snaptastic) from the AppCenter
2. Go to: https://snapcraft.io/vlc
3. Click install

Because it's snap you'll get the latest version, which auto updates and there is less change of damaging your system than when adding custom ppa's.
I recommend using Snaptastic because it's easier, especially for people who don't like using the command line.

Comment: snaptastic had problems with installing.

Comment: Please let the developer know at: https://github.com/bartzaalberg/snaptastic/issues/